# Why do I get a "Borrowed value does not live long enough" error for a value I don't need outside of a function?

Tags: rust

Why does this happen in this certain scenario? I'm new to Rust, read the 2nd edition book, but.. well, yeah, here I am. :)

```
fn main() {
    Xyz::new(&"whatever=123");
}

pub struct Xyz<'a> {
    x: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Xyz<'a> {
    pub fn new(query: &str) -> Result<Xyz<'a>, &'a str> {
        let mut qkey: String = String::new();
        let mut qval: String = String::new();

        let mut is_key = true;
        for (i, c) in query.chars().enumerate().skip(1) {
            if c == '=' {
                is_key = false;
            } else if c == '&' {
                is_key = true;
            } else if is_key {
                qkey.push(c);
            } else {
                qval.push(c);
            }

            if c == '&' || i == query.len() - 1 {
                match qkey.as_ref() {
                    "whatever" => {
                        let _whatever = Xyz::some_func(&mut qval)?;
                    }
                    _ => (),
                }

                qkey.clear();
                qval.clear();
            }
        }
        Ok(Xyz { 
            x: &""
        })
    }

    fn some_func(_val: &mut String) -> Result<bool, &str> {
        Ok(true)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c72a34caabca57a1cf4b592d08df5d1a&version=stable)

Error:

```
error[E0597]: `qval` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:29:61
   |
29 |                         let _whatever = Xyz::some_func(&mut qval)?;
   |                                                             ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
41 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 9:1...
  --> src/main.rs:9:1
   |
9  | impl<'a> Xyz<'a> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't understand why the actual error happens. I know the note should help me understand the problem, but it doesn't.

I don't need `qval` outside of this function, so why do I have to still keep it? Is there a conceptual error I made?

Comment: There are [**38** other questions with this exact error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Borrowed+value+does+not+live+long+enough%22+is%3Aq). The answerers who contribute to Stack Overflow do so with the intent that people in the future will actually *look* at those answers so we can stop answering the same question over and over. This question doesn't demonstrate the basic level of research effort of having looked at *any* of the questions that have already been asked.

Comment: Done, added playground and the error. I have to say though: I actually watched a couple of those questions, none of them seem to explained the issue really. And if there are 38 other questions like this, it seems like there's a reason for that. :)

Comment: The borrow system is to prevent you from referencing memory that has gone out of scope. With your return type `Result<Xyz<'a>, &'a str>`, what scope are you expecting that `&str` to be from? It can't be from the function body, because the function has gone out of scope by then.

Comment: Also in the future please heed the important if _minimal_ in the request above. Your code still reproduces the error with just https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6bfb81812716b0ea1fe3f0d68fae58f2&version=stable

Comment: @loganfsmyth I think I'm starting to understand the problem. So if I'm not mistaken an easy way to solve this would be to just simply return a `String`, instead of `&str`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trimmed down reproduction of your issue is

```
pub struct Xyz<'a> {
    x: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Xyz<'a> {
    pub fn new(_query: &str) -> Result<Xyz<'a>, &'a str> {
        let qval: String = String::new();

        Err(&qval)
    }
}
```

with the error

```
error[E0597]: `qval` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:18
   |
13 |             Err(&qval)
   |                  ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
14 |         }
   |         - borrowed value only lives until here
```

To understand this, I'd recommend taking a step back and thinking about what exactly your function is doing. You create a `String`, and then take a reference to it, and then return that reference.

This is would be a classic case of [use-after-free](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/416.html). From the standpoint of the language, the string no longer exists, so returning a reference to it does not make sense.

Returning `&str` *could* make sense, but only if you can guarantee that the `&str` will only reference data that is still in scope, even after the function has returned. For instance, it would be valid to do `Err(&query)` (or any subsection of `query`) *if* you adjust the function to be `fn new(query: &'a str) ->`, since then it is it is known that the return value lives as long as the input string.

It is hard to tell from your example if that would be acceptable for usecase.

The *simplest* would indeed be to return a `String` (or `Result<Xyz<'a>, String>>` in your case, possibly with a `String` in the field for `Xyz` too). You could also consider returning something like a [Cow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) which is *sometimes* a subsection of `query` or a static string, and *sometimes* a `String`.

As a side-note, I'll also add that `Xyz::new(&"whatever=123");` does not need the `&` since it is already a reference. You can do

```
Xyz::new("whatever=123");
```

just fine. Same for `&""`.

> My confusion was that - in the not stripped down version - both function (`new` and `some_func` returned a global `&'static str` as `Err`, so I thought the compiler would know that the string would always exist.

This may be the core of the misunderstanding. When you declare

```
fn some_func(_val: &mut String) -> Result<bool, &str> {
```

the `&str` is not `'static`. Rust's [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision) logic means that this declaration will assume that the reference in the function argument and the reference in the return value have the same lifetime, meaning that what you've declared is

```
fn some_func<'b>(_val: &'b mut String) -> Result<bool, &'b str> {
```

which triggers the error you are seeing. If you want it to be static, you'll need to say so, as

```
fn some_func(_val: &mut String) -> Result<bool, &'static str> {
```

which would avoid the error, and require that `some_func` always returns a `'static` string.

Comment: I'm not sure the stripped-down reproduction is as helpful as it could be because it ignores the `?` operator which I think is causing part of the confusion, and ignores the rule-of-thumb that a returned reference must come from some input reference which is causing a different kind of confusion.

Comment: Then again, if the OP stripped down their own example we wouldn't have to guess where the confusion stems from...

Comment: Fair point, that's certainly the downside of having to guess.

Comment: @turbulencetoo Well that's my stripped down version. My confusion was that - in the not stripped down version - both function (`new`˙and `some_func` returned a global `&'static str` as Err, so I thought the compiler would know that the string would always exist. It seems like that's not how it works.

Comment: @Andrew Is the expectation that `some_func` will always return `Ok` or static `Err`? Your code would indeed work if you explicitly said `fn some_func(_val: &mut String) -> Result<bool, &'static str>` and thus it never risked returning a non-static string.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Oh my... even `Result<bool, &'a str>` worked. I actually kinda missed that. Thanks! Gotta get used to this. :) Still, what I don't understand is - in my stripped down version - why is it complaining about `qval` not living long enough? Shouldn't it say that the `Err` string that comes from `some_func` doesn't live long enough?

Comment: I updated my answer, see if that helps. Lifetime elision means that the `some_func` return lifetime is tied to the `_val` lifetime, thus tying the return value to `qval`.

Comment: This does a really good job of explaining the why's and the how's behind the most common case for this error, so it's a shame that the question is already at -2. If we could get this answer to turn up higher in the search results there might not be as many duplicates for this error message...